# What does __FILE__ mean?

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, constants

I have the following code from Codeigniter `index.php`

My understanding is that,

If `/` of string position in `$system_folder` (in this case CIcore_1_7_1) is `false`,
and if `realpath` function exists AND (?) is not `false`,
`$system_folder` is assigned to (?) `/$system_folder`.
else `$system_folder` is assigned to `$system_folder` with replacing `\\` with `/`.

Q1. What does realpath function means?

Q2. What does this mean?

```
@realpath(dirname(__FILE__))
```

Q3. Am I right? Do I have any misunderstanding?

Q4. What kind of situation do you need the following?

```
str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder)
```

---

```
$system_folder = "CIcore_1_7_1";

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| SET THE SERVER PATH
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Let's attempt to determine the full-server path to the "system"
| folder in order to reduce the possibility of path problems.
| Note: We only attempt this if the user hasn't specified a 
| full server path.
|
*/

if (strpos($system_folder, '/') === FALSE)
{
    if (function_exists('realpath') AND @realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
    }
}
else
{
    // Swap directory separators to Unix style for consistency
    $system_folder = str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder); 
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. The [`realpath()`](https://php.net/realpath) function gives you the file-system path, with any symbolic links and directory traversing (e.g. ../../) resolved. The [`dirname()`](https://php.net/dirname) function gives you just the directory, not the file within it.
2. [`__FILE__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) is a magic constant that gives you the filesystem path to the current .php file (the one that `__FILE__` is in, not the one it's included by if it's an include.
3. Sounds about right.
4. This is to translate from Windows style (\) paths to Unix style (/).

Comment: Why are there two \s, instead of one \?

Comment: Because \ is the escape character - to put a quote inside a string you use " this is \" a quote". So to put a backslash you need two of them: "this is \\ a backslash"

Comment: excellent answer but I have a question where I can use this constant in PHP

Answer (score 14):

`__FILE__` is simply the name of the current file. `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` gets the name of the directory that the file is in -- in essence, the directory that the app is installed in. And `@` is PHP's extremely silly way of suppressing errors.

Comment: Incorrect, since PHP 4.01 `__FILE__` **always** returns absolute path. 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: amazing thank you so much then I can use this  constants for get the directory that the file ?  for example something like this : $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;

echo $system_folder;

Answer (score 7):

```
__FILE__
```

> The full path and filename of the
>   file. If used inside an include, the
>   name of the included file is returned.
>   Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE** always
>   contains an absolute path with
>   symlinks resolved whereas in older
>   versions it contained relative path
>   under some circumstances.

---

> ```
> string dirname  ( string $path  )
> ```
>
> Given a string containing a path to a file, this function will return
>   the name of the directory.

---

```
str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder)
```

You need this to be consisten in path separators between different operating systems. Windows uses \ and *nix uses /, you keep with /.

Comment: if i want to block this function  in php how  do i should do?

Comment: @simon What do you mean by block?

Answer (score 0):

This echo might help clarify the difference:

````
//  simple-ajax-chat

echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
//  /wp-admin/plugins.php

echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
//  /var/www/path/example.com/httpdocs

echo dirname(__FILE__);
//  /var/www/path/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/simple-ajax-chat

echo getcwd();
//  /var/www/path/example.com/httpdocs/wp-admin

echo __FILE__;
// /var/www/path/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/simple-ajax-chat/simple-ajax-chat.php```
````