# how to call current file in php?

Tags: php

in my code, I am making curl call and after getting response I am calling current file if proper response does not get. like this,

```
<?php
include 'fauxapi_client.php';
$obj = new Fauxapi_client;

$url=$obj->base_url.'/Fauxapi_client/device_version_update';
$version = trim(file_get_contents('/usr/local/www/version.txt'));
$iso_version = trim(file_get_contents('/usr/local/www/iso_version.txt'));
$temp = array('device_ip'=>$obj->current_device_ip,'version'=>$version,'iso_version'=>$iso_version);
$temp = http_build_query($temp);
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $temp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($output === false) {
    echo 'Curl Call Fail';
}
else{
    $response = json_decode($output,true);
    if (isset($response['data']['next_version'])) {
        file_put_contents('/usr/local/www/version.txt', trim($response['data']['next_version']));
        if (floatval($response['data']['max_updatable_version']) > floatval($response['data']['next_version'])) {
            shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/version_update.php");
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'next_version is not in response ';
    }
}
var_dump($output);
?>
```

in the above code

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/version_update.php");
```

is a current file call. 
when I `echo` something there it will `echo` but not calling a current file. so, how to call current file there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506459/what-does-file-mean <- may help

Comment: On some host, for security purpose exec commands are disabled. Have you checked if you are allowed to call `shell_exec`?

Comment: yes, I am allowed to

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the extra space after php? `bin/php /`
And if `/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/version_update.php` is current file you can use `__FILE__` instead it.
And please make sure sufficient permissions.

Comment: using after __FILE__ not any success.