# Django and Stripe, Module 'stripe' has no 'Customer' member

Tags: python, django, frameworks, stripe-payments, payment

so I'm trying to create a customer in stripe using django, according to the documentation in stripe, the code stripe.Customer.create should work, but it just appears this error, can someone tell me why is this happening?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import JsonResponse

import stripe
# Create your views here.
stripe.api_key = "xxxx"

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'sales/index.html')

def charge(request):
    amount = 5
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Data', request.POST)

        stripe.Customer.create(
            email=request.POST['email']
        )

    return redirect(reverse('success', args=[amount]))

def successMsg(request, args):
    amount = args
    return render(request, 'sales/success.html', {'amount':amount})
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\Desktop\django braintree\stripe\sales\views.py", line 17, in charge
    stripe.Customer.create(
AttributeError: module 'stripe' has no attribute 'Customer'
[18/Sep/2020 08:36:39] "POST /charge/ HTTP/1.1" 500 66773
```

Comment: can you paste the traceback?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Likeliest culprit is that the stripe-python library didn't install correctly.

Comment: Hey, I uploaded the traceback, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any file named `stripe.py` in your project? Can you add the complete directory structure to the OP?

Comment: nope, I don't have a stripe.py

Answer (score 7):

The one and only reason for this error is ***you might have either a `stripe.py` file or a module in your project directory.***

and, yes, you have a ***package*** named `stripe` under **`django braintree`** directory.

```
\django braintree\stripe\sales\views.py
```

### How can we verify that?

You can check the ***location of the module*** by inspecting the [**`.__file__`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506459/what-does-file-mean) attribute of the module.

```
import stripe
print(stripe.__file__)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### References

1. [Python Stripe: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charge' -- (StackOverlofw)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830784/python-stripe-module-object-has-no-attribute-charge)
2. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charge' -- (GitHub)](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/226)

Comment: Indeed, OP has a `stripe` module: C:\Users\snin2\Desktop\django braintree\ **stripe** \sales\views.py.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your project/app as **stripe** which makes conflict with the stripe package you installed

Change you project/app name to a different name and try again

NOTE: avoid using package name as app name or project name, this will create issues during referencing